# Having two tables of users id and the link between them

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have the first table 'users'

```
| id    | name
------------------
| 1     |  james 
| 2     |  johnny
| 3     |  Carl 
| 4     |  Lea
```

And my second table contain the linked users
linked_users

```
| id    | linked_id 
--------------------
| 1     | 2   
| 1     | 4   
| 2     | 3
```

I need to get two fields containing the name of each user with the name of the linked user.

I tried this one but it's not working properly.

```
SELECT case WHEN u.user_id = l.user_id then user_name end as username,
case WHEN u.user_id = l.link_user_id then user_name end as linked
FROM
   panel_user u, link_view_user l WHERE l.link_user_id = u.user_id
```

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join the panel_user table twice to the link_view_user table. Once with the id and then with the link_user_id column.

```
SELECT u2.name as id_name, u1.name as linked_id_name
FROM link_view_user l
join panel_user u1 on u1.id = l.linked_id
join panel_user u2 on u2.id = l.id
```

Comment: It would help though if you added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u1.name AS username, 
       u2.name AS linked
FROM linked_users lu 
INNER JOIN users u1 ON lu.id = u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON lu.linked_id  = u2.id
```